# Adding control to page after some operation MVC3

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I will start by saying I am very new to MVC3 and just need some general direction.

I currently have a MVC3 webpage with a DevExpress Upload Control.  The upload control parses the selected document and calls a webservice with data obtained from the file.  I want to display the webservice response in a devexpress grid (which I have in a partial view) but can not figure out how to instantiate it until after the results from the webservice have been recieved.

Here's what I have so far...

Index.cshtml

```
<div id="form" style="float:left; margin-left:50px;">
<p>Select a file to upload:</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StepUpdater", FormMethod.Post, new { id="uploadForm", name="uploadForm" }))
{
    @Html.DevExpress().UploadControl(settings =>
       {
           settings.Name = "uploadController";
           settings.Width = 325;
           settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "StepUpdater", Action = "CallbacksUpload" };
           settings.UploadButton.
       }).GetHtml()

    <label style="color:Red">@TempData["Error"]</label>

    @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "uploadButton";
            settings.Text = " Upload";
            settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
            settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s,e){uploadController.Upload();}";
        }).GetHtml()
}

<br />

@Html.Partial("GridViewPartial", (IEnumerable<StepResponse>)Model)
```

GridViewPartial.cshtml

```
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings => {
    settings.Name = "Responses";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "StepUpdater", Action =         "GridViewPartial" };
    settings.Settings.ShowColumnHeaders = true;
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Then the Controller

```
    private IEnumerable<StepResponse> responses  = new List<StepResponse>();
    public IEnumerable<StepResponse> Responses
    {
        get { return responses; } 
        set { responses = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Responses);
    }

    public ActionResult GridViewPartial()
    {
        if (Responses == null)
            Responses = new List<StepResponse>();

        return PartialView("GridViewPartial", Responses);
    }



    public ActionResult CallbacksUpload()
    {
        UploadControlExtension.GetUploadedFiles("uploadController", new ValidationSettings { AllowedFileExtensions = new []{ ".csv" }}, uploadControl_FileUploadCompleted);
        return GridViewPartial();
    }

    .... steps to parse csv and put results in Responses object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are uploading a file via the client-side Upload method.

You can update the GridView in the following manner:

1) Handle the "**CallbacksUpload**" Action and process the uploaded file;

2) Store information about the uploaded and planned web service call via the Session state, for example;

3) Handle the client-side **FileUploadComplete** event as illustrated in the online ["File Upload - AJAX Uploading"](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/UploadControl/Callbacks) demo;

4) Perform a custom GridView's callback via the client-side **PerformCallback** method as illustrated in the online ["Grid View - Grouping"](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/GridView/Grouping) demo;

4) Handle the "**GridViewPartial**" Action, execute a web service call, populate the GridView's Model, and return the "**GridViewPartial**" PartialView with this Model.